# I accidentally deleted all admin accounts [13.04]

Tags: root, password-recovery

I accidentally deleted all admin accounts, I can only use Guest Account and I don't know my root password. How can I recover my Admin account?

Comment: You cannot "recover" what you deleted. Besides: How can you "accidentally" delete all Admin accounts? You screwed around to much, didn't you? :D Sorry, but it is kinda funny to me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have an existing home directory and that you want to reassociate your user with that directory.

1. Reboot into recovery. Hold <kbd>Left Shift</kbd> at boot, select "Other options" then pick the latest recovery mode.
2. Pick "root shell prompt" when the recovery menu loads.
3. Run the following:

   ```
   mount -o remount,rw /
   adduser --home /home/username --no-create-home <username> sudo
   sudo reboot
   ```

Then you should be able to log in.

Comment: I dont know anything, but I clicked "delete" in the User Management Page.